# Using imap_search filters in PHP

Tags: php, email, imap, pop3

I need to filter the mails on the basis of the available headers.

I did for "To" field using something like "TO: admin@mysite.com", but I also need to apply filter to "From" field, but the from field is dynamic — it can be admin@yoursite.com or support@yoursite.com or any other@yoursite.com domain, so the from field is never the same. So I was wanting to know if there is any "like" filter for "From" field ,or any better solution, so I can set something like "%@yoursite.com" so it will be dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring for [imap_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) function, so the following code should work in your case:

```
imap_search($conn, 'TO "admin@mysite.com" FROM "@yoursite.com"');
```

**Edit**: removed the `@` sign from the search.

**Edit2**: I looked in both the RFC mentioned on the `imap_search` page, i.e. [2060](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2060.html) and [1176](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1176), they don't say nothing about `@` sign in the address, neither for any other character which should not be used when searching in addresses.

I tried this code on my mailserver and it does work, so `@` is allowed when searching for addresses (it'd be useless if haven't).

```
<?php
$conn   = imap_open('{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'foo@example.com', 'pass123', OP_READONLY);

$some   = imap_search($conn, 'FROM "@example.com"', SE_UID);
```

So you can definitely use the `@`, since it will match what you've requested.

Comment: @PowerfulDevelopmentTeam that's strange because it works for me with substrings. In my case I was searching for a partial subject, maybe partial search doesn't work for addresses. Try it with just the from part (without the @ char) to see if partial match is allowed in addresses, i.e. `imap_search($conn, 'FROM "yoursite.com"');`

Comment: one more help plz, how can i add multiple domains in "FROM" field like. i tried using multiple "FROM" and also tried using seperating the domains with delimeter " " and "," but neither worked. can u help on this???

Comment: @PowerfulDevelopmentTeam you can use boolean operators in your search such as "NOT TO example.com OR FROM example.org". Don't know if you can use parentheses in your expression, maybe you should try. Read about searching in section [6.4.4 of this document](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2060.html)

Comment: Well, then I think that you can't, nevertheless imap is not a database ;-) You can always do two different searches and merge the results.

Comment: solid triple negative in there. hard to do.

Comment: 'merge' or 'array_intersect' as appropiate.